# Copying Firmware

Tags: pic, firmware, pickit

I have a PIC chip with a firmware. I have another identical microprocessor, but it's empty. I need to copy the firmware from the programmed PIC to the empty one. I don't have the original code. The microprocessor is the PIC12f629. 
Is this possible ? How could I do it ?

Thanks ,

Liam

Comment: You've tagged your question with 'pickit'. Do you have one of those? Do you know how to use it?

Comment: It is possible to read the first processor's xram and get the hex code if you haven't locked it. and you can burn the hex on the other processor. but you can never know the code unless you understand binary.

Comment: Hi brhans, I have the Pickit 3. I'm assuming that I would need it to copy the firmware

Comment: Hi BluSky, I don't need the actual code, I just need a replica. Reading the Xram is a very good idea. How is that done ? How do I find out if it was was locked ?

Comment: idk how PIC is different with AVR. but in AVR you can read xram via SPI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code does not have the protection fuses set, you can hook up your PICKit and "Read" the data off the device with the PICKit programming utility.

If you get all 0x00s or all 0xffs, that is a bad sign.

You can save the result to a .hex file or whatever you choose. Now just burn that onto your new chip-- that should work, though I've never done it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Do you know of any links that could show me how to do this ?

Comment: Also, if the protection fuses were set, is there any way of bypassing them ?

Comment: Not without a lot of hacking knowledge, or maybe not at all. That's what the protection fuses are protecting from...copying